# About default routing helpers, is there some redundancy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, routes, helper

Assuming `post = Post.first`, I can write a link with

```
link_to "First Post", post  # I guess Rails here understand to which model the
                            # object "post" belongs
```

But to edit the post, the link is

```
link_to "Edit First Post", edit_post_path(post)
```

Is it possible to write something like:

```
link_to "Edit First Post", post, :type => :edit
```

so that it would be not necessary to specify to which model the object belong? Would not that be DRYer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `method` and `action` instead of `type`

See the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Example:

```
link_to "Profile", :controller => "profiles", :action => "show", :id => @profile
# => <a href="/profiles/show/1">Profile</a>
```

Comment: You are right. But I was wondering if was possible to make rails to generate an edit link just with two type piece of data (object, type of link), in your example you are giving three (controller, action, id of object).

Comment: Could you try `link_to "Edit", post, :action => :edit` ? I can't test it from where I am, but I think it may work.

Comment: Reading the [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), I'm not sure that you can add something more. `edit_post_path(:id)` seems to be the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution that I implemented. In `application_helper.rb` add the method:

```
def edit_path(item, other = {})
  send("edit_#{item.class.to_s.downcase}_path", item, other)
end
```

So now I can create edit links with:

```
link_to "Edit Post", edit_path(post)
link_to "Edit User", edit_path(user)
```

instead of

```
link_to "Edit Post", edit_post_path(post)
link_to "Edit User", edit_user_path(user)
```

I feel this is DRYer, but maybe it is just me.